# Elastic search improve duplicate removal

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, duplicates, json.net, nest

I have query below that removes duplicates per each index value. It first sort by name and then takes top first element for each key. Is there any way to write a query, such that it will analyse all index value items -keys  and remove duplicates without doing so manually in asp.net? (possible one list of unique results?)

Query used:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "query": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "size": 0,
  "query": {

          "multi_match": {
            "query": "laura",
            "operator": "OR",
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ]
          }
  }
}
```

Result retrieved:

```
        "aggregations": {
            "query": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 3,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "laura",
                  "doc_count": 15,
                  "top": {
                    "hits": {
                      "total": 15,
                      "max_score": 4.240788,
                      "hits": [
                        {
        "eventCode": 1011020,
        "name": "LAURA MVULA", /* Not duplicated*/
        ...
        },
        {
                  "key": "mvula",
                  "doc_count": 11,
                  "top": {
                    "hits": {
                      "total": 11,
                      "max_score": 4.240788,
                      "hits": [
                        {
        "eventCode": 1011020,
        "name": "LAURA MVULA", /* Duplicate!*/
        ...
        },
        {
                  "key": "lexx",
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "top": {
                    "hits": {
                      "total": 2,
                      "max_score": 3.3926303,
                      "hits": [
                        {
        "eventCode": 1009639,
        "name": "LAURA LEXX: TYRANNOSAURUS LEXX", /* Not duplicated*/
        ...
        }

Settings used:

    ...
                  "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                      "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                      }
                    }
                  },
    ...
```

Mapping used:

```
...
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              },
...
```

Comment: If you insert duplicate records into index, then it will return same. In your scenario "name": "LAURA MVULA" coming twice, but _id is different for those 2 records. Please check.

Comment: @vinod_vh Thank you for your response. Ids for the first two records are the same -  "eventCode": 1011020, but for the "lexx" it will return "eventCode": 1009639.  Is there any way to make "LAURA MVULA" to come only once as first two result ids are the same, without making any modification on the database i.e. removing ?

Comment: Can you please share full record for "eventCode": 1011020. I want to see your document how it is..?

Comment: @vinod_vh Please check the link for full snippet. Thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/fs0roa27/

Comment: I can see "_id": "1011020" is twice in your data, because of that you are getting twice in your query results.

Comment: @vinod_vh True. Can I do something in elastic search aggregations to remove those duplicates? Otherwise I will have to do it manually in c# code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126832/discussion-between-proglearner-and-vinod-vh).

Comment: eventCode `1011020` appearing in both `laura` and `mvula` buckets of a terms aggregation is not a duplicate; the document is a match for both buckets. Maybe you can edit your question to provide more details for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @RussCam Thanks for your response. I am implementing auto complete function and using current aggregation settings it returns unique documents for each key, but considering all keys in a single list, some results will remain duplicated. So, it would be good if I would be able to put all those results in a single list or something similar and get distinct results considering all keys, not only per key. Thank you.